# Filter an R array based on colnames and rownames

Tags: arrays, r

I have a 3D array, where the rownames and colnames of the inner matrices are datestamp strings. I want to separate it into two 3D arrays:

- row is after column (NAs if before or equal)
- row is before/equal column (NAs if after)

Here is some test data:

```
dimnames = list(
  c("A", "B"),
  c("2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01"),
  c("2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01")
  )
v = array(1:24,
  dim = lapply(dimnames,length),
  dimnames = dimnames
  )
```

And then I want to perform some magic here:

```
ret = split_it_up(v)
v1 = ret[[1]]
v2 = ret[[2]]
```

And then `v1["A",,]` will look like this:

```
           2015-12-01 2016-01-01 2016-02-01 2016-03-01
2015-12-01         NA         NA         NA         NA
2016-01-01          3         NA         NA         NA
2016-02-01          5         11         NA         NA
```

while `v2["A",,]` will look like this:

```
           2015-12-01 2016-01-01 2016-02-01 2016-03-01
2015-12-01          1          7         13         19
2016-01-01         NA          9         15         21
2016-02-01         NA         NA         17         23
```

(and `v1["B",,]` and `v2["B",,]` will have been split in the same way.)

Inspired by the way `lower.tri()` works, my best attempt so far is with a 2D matrix (e.g. `vx = v["A",,]`) I can do this:

```
matrix(
  as.character(row(vx,as.factor=T)) > as.character(col(vx,as.factor=T)),
  c(3,4))
```

which gives:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But then I cannot quite work out what to do with it, let alone how to get it to work for all slices of a 3D array.

**UPDATE:**

Some different test data, to make sure a solution is not making assumptions about the ordering of the rows and columns.

```
dimnames = list(
  c("A", "B"),
  c("2016-01-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-02-01"),
  c("2016-02-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-01-01")
  )
v = array(1:24,
  dim = lapply(dimnames,length),
  dimnames = dimnames
  )
```

`v["A",,]` looks like:

```
           2016-02-01 2015-12-01 2016-03-01 2016-01-01
2016-01-01          1          7         13         19
2015-12-01          3          9         15         21
2016-02-01          5         11         17         23
```

`v1["A",,]` will be:

```
           2016-02-01 2015-12-01 2016-03-01 2016-01-01
2016-01-01         NA          7         NA         NA
2015-12-01         NA         NA         NA         NA
2016-02-01         NA         11         NA         23
```

`v2["A",,]` will be:

```
           2016-02-01 2015-12-01 2016-03-01 2016-01-01
2016-01-01          1         NA         13         19
2015-12-01          3          9         15         21
2016-02-01          5         NA         17         NA
```

And another more extreme example:

```
dimnames = list(
  c("A", "B"),
  c("2015-10-01", "2015-12-01", "2015-11-01"),
  c("2016-02-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-01-01")
  )
v = array(1:24,
  dim = lapply(dimnames,length),
  dimnames = dimnames
  )
```

Here all columns are greater than all rows. So `v1` will be all NAs, and `v2` will be identical to `v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for `splice.index` comparing the "dimnames" of the last two dimensions:

```
# using "v" of your second example (first after update)
dnm2 = dimnames(v)[[2]][slice.index(v, 2)]
dnm3 = dimnames(v)[[3]][slice.index(v, 3)]

v1 = replace(v, dnm2 <= dnm3, NA)
v2 = replace(v, dnm2 > dnm3, NA)

v1["A", , ]
#           2016-02-01 2015-12-01 2016-03-01 2016-01-01
#2016-01-01         NA          7         NA         NA
#2015-12-01         NA         NA         NA         NA
#2016-02-01         NA         11         NA         23
v2["A", , ]
#           2016-02-01 2015-12-01 2016-03-01 2016-01-01
#2016-01-01          1         NA         13         19
#2015-12-01          3          9         15         21
#2016-02-01          5         NA         17         NA
v1["B", , ]
v2["B", , ]
```

Comment: Thanks; I'd not heard of `slice.index`, and `replace` had somehow passed me by too. Unfortunately, this is working by coincidence: slice.index() just returns row and column integers, but I need it to be comparing on the character strings. I've added a couple of examples to the question. 
`slice.index()` doesn't have the `as.factor` argument that `row()` and `col()` have, but if it did I think your solution could be made to work?

Comment: Got it! If you first do: `ix2 = dimnames(v)[[2]][slice.index(v, 2)]` and `ix3 = dimnames(v)[[3]][slice.index(v, 3)]`, then it can be written as `v1 = replace(v, ix2 <= ix3, NA)` and `v2 = replace(v, ix2 > ix3, NA)`   (If you agree, could you update your answer?)

Comment: @DarrenCook : Yes, I believe your workaround seems appropriate; I missed that the `dimnames` should be compared. I'll update according to your comment